# Short IF throws TypeError, normal if works just fine - same conditions, why?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the first scenario i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`, second one works just fine. From my point of view these two IF statements are equal. Am I wrong?

Consider following code fragments:

```
return array[index].id ? array[index] : undefined
```

and

```
if (array[index]) {
  return array[index].id
} else {
  return undefined
}
```

Comment: Try the answer Ankit gave. In the second case you are checking whether array[index] is true whereas in the ternary operator it is in reverse.

Comment: yeah, looks like I made a terrible mistake here :)

Comment: Please actually read the error message! `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` means `array[index]` doesn't have the property `id`.

Comment: `array[index].id` implicitly assumes that `array[index]` is defined. If you want to use the ternary operator in this case, you have to do: `(array[index] && array[index].id) ? array[index].id : undefined;`, otherwise if array[index] is undefined it will throw a type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary condition is incorrect it should be:

```
return array[index] ? array[index].id : undefined
```

It should check that `array[index]` exist and it is defined then return `array[index].id` else `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, this is what he is looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
return array[index].id ? array[index] : undefined
```

Is equal to:

```
if (array[index].id) {
  return array[index]
} else {
  return undefined
}
```